# How can I stop the time from displaying in a GridView when displaying a date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gridview

I have a web application that I am working on(ASP.NET 2.0 & C#). In it, I have a gridview that gets data from an Oracle Database. Some of the data that I need to display is dates. But when the dates in my gridview show like this:

> 2009-04-02 00:00:00

I'd prefer they show without the time. I'm using the codebehind to get the data, so I cant alter the fields of the gridview manually. This is all the code for my gridview :

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." ></asp:GridView>
```

How do I stop the time from displaying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply a `dataformatstring` in the `gridview` column to only show the date.

To get it to work you must make sure that `HTMLEncode` is set to `false`.

[More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

if you set your datasource programmatically (code behind), you can still have all your columns in the gridview (use asp:DataBoundColumn)

```
DataFormatString="{0:d}"
```

#### EDIT

this code is for your aspx page, if you really want to stick your presentation logic in your code behind - you have 2 options:

1. format the Date on "RowDataBound" event
2. format the Date in your query - that way you won't have to deal with formatting in code at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use
 DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False"

do not forget to use the last section [htmlencode]

I hope this works ... this works for me !!!!

Arunendra