# How to put negative number in brackets in a Grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I stop the time from displaying in a GridView when displaying a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711004/how-can-i-stop-the-time-from-displaying-in-a-gridview-when-displaying-a-date)

I have Grid view with negative number in column called “Total”, I like to put all the negative number in brackets.

#### e.g.

```
Total
76  
(-66)
646  
(-76)  
(-10)  
(-6) 
16  
676
```

I am using ASP.NET with C#, how should i go about it.

or can I do it In SQL Query; as Grid view is being populated via sql datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this simple example. I am using a Gridview:

C#

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> x = new List<int>() { 76, -66, 646, -76, -10, -6, 16, 676 };
        this.GridView1.DataSource = x;
        this.GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[0].Text) < 0)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "(" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + ")";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Item
76
(-66)
646
(-76)
(-10)
(-6)
16
676
```

Good luck

Edit: I would NOT  modify the SQL's outpupt to make it work just for this.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something similar to Hanlet Escano but instead of parsing, I would case the data object like this:

Default.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvGrid_RowDataBound">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="litData" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Default.aspx.cs

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          //Generate Data
          var data = new List() { 76, -66, 646, -76, -10, -6, 16, 676 };

```
      gvGrid.DataSource = data;
      gvGrid.DataBind();
    }
  }

  protected void gvGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      //Strongly Type Controls
      var litData = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("litData");

      //Strongly Type Data
      var data = (int)e.Row.DataItem;

      //Display Data
      if (data < 0)
      {
        litData.Text = "[" + data.ToString() + "]";
      }
      else
      {
        litData.Text = data.ToString();
      }
    }
  }
```

There are several advantages to this, the data is already stored in its native form (int), it just is in an object variable.

Second, if in the future you needed to handle multiple columns with more complex data objects (a Person/Business/Foo/Bar objects) this same technique could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onRowDataBound event of the gridview and update the cell however you want, add brackets and stuff :)

Check it out:

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread9403-get-the-particular-value-in-gridview-using-rowdatabound-in-csharpnet.aspx